# Does the django "in" clause require the list to have two values?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

Question: Does the django "in" clause require the list to have two values?

I was writing some raw queries in django and I was noticing that the same query would crash depending on the values given to it. In both cases the rawqueryset is created, the crash occurs when I try to evaluate it.

Specifically:
This queryset would crash

```
<RawQuerySet: 'select * from (select * from flingfix_user_profile where domain=illinois and sex=F)
as a left outer join (select * from flingfix_rating where rater_id=24) as b ON
a.id = b.ratee_id where rater_id IS NULL and a.id not in [0] LIMIT 10'>
```

but this queryset would not

```
<RawQuerySet: 'select * from (select * from flingfix_user_profile where domain=illinois and sex=F)
as a left outer join (select * from flingfix_rating where rater_id=24) as b ON
a.id = b.ratee_id where rater_id IS NULL and a.id not in [0,1] LIMIT 10'>
```

(The difference is [0] vs [0,1] near the end of the query)

I am building the query using the following code:

```
query = 'select * from (select * from flingfix_user_profile where
domain=%s and sex=%s) as a left outer join (select * from flingfix_rating where
rater_id=%s) as b ON a.id = b.ratee_id where rater_id IS NULL and a.id 
not in %s LIMIT %s'

params = ['illinois', 'F', '24', [0], 10]

qs = MyModel.objects.raw(query,params)
```

The error does not occur until I try to evaluate the queryset. E.g. `qs = list(qs)`

Here is the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1548, in     __iter__
query = iter(self.query)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 72, in __iter__
self._execute_query()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 86, in _execute_query
self.cursor.execute(self.sql, self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 41, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 130, in execute
six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 120, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 173, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
DatabaseError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to yo
ur MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') LIMIT 10' at line 1")
```

I mean, I could easily just ensure that the list is at least 2 elements long, but I would prefer not to. Also, I was curious as to why this would happen.

Comment: Since this is a raw query, the question has nothing at all to do with Django or Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL `in` clause usually requires 0 or more values listed between *parenthesis*, not square brackets. You are generating invalid SQL.

You need to generate the appropriate number of SQL parameters instead of passing in a list here:

```
query = 'select * from (select * from flingfix_user_profile where
domain=%s and sex=%s) as a left outer join (select * from flingfix_rating where
rater_id=%s) as b ON a.id = b.ratee_id where rater_id IS NULL and a.id 
not in ({}) LIMIT %s'.format(','.join(['%s' for _ in range(len(parameters))]))
```

where `parameters` is the list of values you want to test `not in` against, and pass in those parameters as elements of the `params` list:

```
params = ['illinois', 'F', '24'] + parameters + [10]
qs = MyModel.objects.raw(query,params)
```

The above query adjustment now generates `not in (%s, %s)` for two values, `not in (%s)` for just one, and the parameters will be handled correctly by MySQL from that point on.

Comment: So then why does the second query work? I was originally turning the list into a tuple so that it would have the parenthesis instead of square brackets, but the same problem occurs. I figured that django was doing some more work before actually evaluating the queryset. Maybe if it sees a list/tuple that is only 1 long it removes the parens/brackets?

Comment: Actually, you can see that the error says `near ') LIMIT 10'`, so that means that there is a parenthesis there when it is actually evaluating the query.

Comment: @MatthewWesly: That's the nested select, *not* the `in [..]` before it. The parser errors out there it expects something else to follow a square bracketed expression.

Comment: @MatthewWesly: just because the expression with `[0, 1]` made sense in SQL *syntax* doesn't mean that the *result* is correct.

Comment: I'm confused. The nested select is not near `LIMIT 10`. How could that paren belong to the nested select? And the result of the expression with [0, 1] is correct, the query evaluates and it is the result I was expecting. Am I understanding something incorrectly?

Comment: @MatthewWesly: ah, I see what you mean, it may be that the MySQL query parser either tries too hard to interpret what you mean and tried to replace square brackets with parenthesis. Fact is, that the MySQL SQL dialect doesn't support square brackets **at all** officially, and such behaviour is certainly not documented.

Comment: @MatthewWesly: I would *certainly* not rely on the behaviour; undocumented behavior or side-effects have a habit of disappearing between versions, and it certainly tripping up your code here when there is only one value.

Comment: @MatthewWesly: it may also be an artifact of the way the Django MySQL adapter parses the parameters, turning `[0]` into a tuple, which would be `(0,)` which is invalid SQL as well; `[0, 1]` would become `(0, 1)`. Again. this is a side-effect, not intended behaviour, and would break if you had anything other than integers in that list.

Comment: Okay, so it turns out that you can check the raw queries that django executes by importing `connection` from `django.db`. The queries are then in `connection.queries`.
After looking at the raw query, it was indeed turning `[0]` into a tuple which displayed as `(0,)`. Your solution worked, though I had to change `({})` to `({0})`. Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewWesly: ah, yes, for Python 2.6 you'd need to explicitly number the placeholders. I often forget this. Glad I was of help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

in where clause instead:

```
and a.id not in [0,1] LIMIT 10 OR
a.id not in [0] LIMIT 10
```

you should write like this:

```
and a.id not in (0,1) LIMIT 10 OR
a.id not in (0) LIMIT 10
```